# Azure Application Gateway http/2 not working

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I have enabled Http2 in Azure portal in Application gateway configuration.

Also, I am accessing it using https and have min version set to TLS 1.2

Still, when accessing it from browser, Chrome dev tools report protocol http 1.1 is being used.

Am I missing something?